# PHP returning different parts of a function based on arguments

Tags: php, function, parameters

Is there a way to return only part of a function based on what is passed within the ()? As an example:

```
function test($wo) {

if function contains $wo and "date" {
//pass $wo through sql query to pull date
return $date
}

if function contains $wo and "otherDate" {
//pass $wo through another sql query to pull another date
return $otherDate

}

if function only contains $wo {
//pass these dates through different methods to get a final output 
return $finaldate

}

}
```

Date:

```
test($wo, date);
```

Returns:

```
1/1/2015
```

otherDate:

```
test($wo, otherDate);
```

Returns:

```
10/01/2015
```

Normal output:

```
test($wo);
```

Returns:

```
12/01/2015
```

Comment: You're going to have to give a better example with expected input/output, etc...

Comment: Hopefully it is more clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an argument that specifies what to return:

```
function test($wo, $type='final') {
    // pull $date
    if($type == 'date') { return $date; }
    // pull $otherdate
    if($type == 'other') { return $otherdate; }
    // construct $finaldate
    if($type == 'final') { return $finaldate; }

    return false;
}
```

Then call like:

```
$something = test($a_var, 'other');
// or for final since it is default
$something = test($a_var);
```

Comment: switch/case may be a good suggestion as well.

Comment: @SuperJer:  yes, I started that way but if $date and $other are both needed for $final I didn't want cases that fell thru to the next one.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was needing

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague but if I understand correctly, you want optional arguments. You can make function arguments optional by providing a default value for them in the function definition:

```
// $a is required
// $b is optional and defaults to 'test' if not specified
// $c is optional and defaults to null if not specified
function test($a, $b = 'test', $c = null)
{
    echo "a is $a\n";
    echo "b is $b\n";
    echo "c is $c\n";
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
test(1, 'foo', 'bar');
```

And you get:

```
a is 1
b is foo
c is bar
```

Or this:

```
test(37);
```

And you get:

```
a is 37
b is test
c is
```